# how to add children in a node in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i am trying to upload multiple images at once in the firebase. i have a thumbnail image and three other main images to be uploaded at once , while i am able to upload them successfully in the firebase storage, i find it annoying to reference the path to image in the database.

To upload the images :
1.) I am performing an upload task to put one thumbnail image along with other data. This is how the database looks like after uploading the thumbnail image:

[image]

2.) then i run the for loop for uploading other three images to the database, the images are uploaded in the storage. But in the database, under the unique key node i don't get a child containing all the three image urls that i have uploaded in the storage.

This is what i want the database to look like:

[image]

my code for uploading images :

```
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://myProject-3j45.appspot.com")

    let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
    let imgRef = storage.child("posts").child(uid!).child("\(key).jpeg")


    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coverImageData!, 0.8)
    let uploadTask = imgRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, Error) in
        if Error != nil {
            print(Error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        }
        imgRef.downloadURL { (url, err) in
            if let url = url {
                let feed = ["pathToImage" : url.absoluteString ,
                            "likes" : 0 ,
                            "creator" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName as Any,
                            "description" : describeData ,
                            "content" : contentData ,
                    ] as [String : Any]
                let postFeed = ["\(key)" : feed]
                ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(postFeed)
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    uploadTask.resume()
    print(imageUploaded)


    for _ in images {
        if imageUploaded != imageToUpload {

            // for multiple images upload process 
            let mainKey = ref.child(key).childByAutoId().childByAutoId().key
            let mainImageRef = storage.child("posts").child(uid!).child("\(mainKey).jpeg")

            let mainData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images.first!, 0.7)
            let mainUploadTask = mainImageRef.putData(mainData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, Error) in
                if Error != nil {
                    print(Error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                    return
                }
                mainImageRef.downloadURL { (mainUrl, err) in
                    if let url = mainUrl {
                        let feeder = ["url" : url.absoluteString ] as [String : Any]
                        let mainImgUrls = ["\(key)" : feeder]
                        ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(mainImgUrls)
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            mainUploadTask.resume()
            imageUploaded += 1
            images.removeFirst()
            print(imageUploaded)
        } else if imageUploaded == imageToUpload {
            print(imageUploaded)
            return
        }
```

Comment: So I'm a bit of a noob, but when I put your code into a file and `import Firebase` I get  these unresolved identifiers 'Storage, coverImageData, imageUploaded, and images. Is this all of your code?

Comment: @Sam yup! i tried to problem specific so omitted those in the question

Comment: Ok, if there's no issue with it could you upload your project to github maybe and I could take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

you try change this line

```
ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(mainImgUrls)
```

for this

```
ref.child("posts/mainImages/url_1").setValue(url.absoluteString)
```

you have the cycle for, you should to change url_1 each time to save new url

Comment: it created a child "mainImages" but removed all the other values . The database now contains, post -> mainImage -> url_1 , also the thumbnail image is now not being uploaded in the storage side